# Finding all possible combinations of sum product to reach a given target

Tags: python, python-3.x

There has been a solution to find the possible combination of numbers to reach a given target number. However, I have a different situation below, where a,b, and c are product types and I like to find the combination of sum products of a,b and c to reach the target total.

```
a = 50sqft
b = 70sqft
c = 100sqft

Total = 5000sqft
```

I like to find all possible combinations of numbers (integer solution) of a,b,c to get to 5000, and how can I create a python function for that?

```
Results :

(100a,0b,0c)=5000
(23a,5b,8c)=5000
...
...
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll have to write code, which you apparently have not even attempted to do.

Comment: There are an infinite possible combinations if you consider non-integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution :

```
a=50
b=70
c=100

for i in range(101): # This si 101 here to give 100a=5000
    for j in range(100):
        for k in range(100):
            if i*a + j*b + k*c == 5000:
                print('({}a,{}b,{}c)=5000'.format(i,j,k))
```

Comment: Those are just integer solutions and that's not even all of them

Comment: Question doesn't mention non-integers solutions and there is all solutions for integers

Comment: Thank you Sozy! Yes, I'm looking for integer solutions. Your code gave me a good start as I am not a developer and looking for a computational method to solve the solution. Thanks again.